Trouble with NetworkDriver.Create in Unity Networking
I'm encountering an issue while using the NetworkDriver.Create method in Unity Networking and I could use some assistance.
Here's the code snippet where I'm facing the problem:
s_networkDriver = NetworkDriver.Create(new ReliableUtility.Parameters { WindowSize = 32 });

Whenever I run this line, I receive the following error:
error CS0315: The type 'Unity.Networking.Transport.Utilities.ReliableUtility.Parameters' cannot be used as type parameter 'N' in the generic type or method 'NetworkDriver.Create<N>(N)'. There is no boxing conversion from 'Unity.Networking.Transport.Utilities.ReliableUtility.Parameters' to 'Unity.Networking.Transport.INetworkInterface'.

I'm not entirely sure what this error means or how to resolve it. Can someone please provide some guidance on how to properly use NetworkDriver.Create in Unity Networking?

There is no overload of NetworkDriver.Create() which expects the argument to be a ReliableUtility.Parameters value.
I haven't used the Transport package, but from some quick looking at the API docs, you probably need to do something like this:
NetworkDriver CreateDriver(Allocator allocator) {
    var settings = new NetworkSettings(allocator);
    settings.AddRawParameterStruct(new ReliableUtility.Parameters { WindowSize = 32 });
    var networkDriver = NetworkDriver.Create(settings);
    return networkDriver;
}

See also https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.transport@2.2/api/Unity.Networking.Transport.NetworkSettings.html
